# How to compile Material.io design with gulp-sass without using Webpack?

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, material-components-web

I'm using [this tutorial at Material.io](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/) and want to use Material.io with gulp-sass.
But when I try to compile it, it shows the error

> @material\button\mdc-button.scss
>   Error: Invalid CSS after "@include mixins": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ".core-styles;"

The repository is located [at GitHUB](https://github.com/Balmat/material-compo).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to use node-sass. MDC Web Components version 5 uses the [Sass Modules](https://sass-lang.com/blog/the-module-system-is-launched) syntax, which is currently only supported by Dart Sass.

```
npm install sass
```

Then in gulpfile.js:

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
sass.compiler = require('sass');
```

Comment: Man your answer should be accepted. You saved me a lot of hours of work. Thanks. GOD bless.

Comment: 100% agree this should be the accepted answer, you saved my bacon!